# Implementation of comunication between server and clients

Tags: c#, .net

I am looking for ideas of possible solution of my programming problem .

I have a server pc and about 50 client computers , I should path a massages in both ways between the server and the clients . All computers sit on some local network , and the rate of massages between the server and client is really low .

I though  to implement this thing by named pipes but there is a limitation of max 10 pipes under windows xp , this is the environment that they are using .

Any better ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Windows Communication Foundation (WCF)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx). You can host these services in IIS on your server, or you could look at implementing an ASP.NET web service instead. The web service would probably be the easiest solution.

There are lots of options available in .NET, but WCF is one of the newest additions to the framework for this kind of thing.

Comment: WCF seems like the way to go here. Its easy to implement and deploy and you should be able to scale up the number of clients quite easily

Answer (score 0):

If they are connected in LAN, then you can use sockets

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/chandrasekar.aspx